# Specifying a port location

Tags: jointjs

I have a diagramming solution I am working on, using custom elements based on devs.Model which are dynamically created at runtime. The elements might each have one or more inPorts and outPorts. I'm trying to specify the Y portion of the position for each port based on the contents.

Currently I loop through the objects I am diagramming and construct the markup for each element, and keep track of the inPort and outPorts I need to create. Once I have built the markup I need, I instantiate the element, specifying markup, size, position, and port group configurations (color and size so far).

Then I loop through the inPort and outPort collections I have built and add the port using *el1.addOutPort(name)* or *el1.addInPort(name)*. In the documentation it refers to an [opts] object that can be passed, but there doesn't seem to be clear documentation of what it can contain, or at least, I don't see anything to specify where the port gets placed.

Here's a sample image of what i get now

[image: Here's a sample image of what i get now]

I am trying to get it so that both ports on both sides (in this case) show up in the same box as the text 'process'.

I'm hoping this is something I've just been overlooking, thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @xmojmr

Answer (score 2):

While it might not be the best solution, here is what I came up with. I'm posting the answer in case someone in the future is trying to figure out the same issue.

I had been adding my ports using

```
el1.addOutPort(portName);
```

and was trying to find code I could add to that for the opts.

I went back to the jointjs site, and went through their tutorials until I saw one that was specifically positioning the ports and looked at the source code. Based on that, and after some experimentation, I came up with

```
el1.addPort({ group: 'out', id: portName, args: { y: yPosition+offset }});
```

And here's the result

[image: And here's the result (if someone could inline this image it would be appreciated)]